# npm start not working - issue with package/react script

Tags: node.js, reactjs

For one of my react app, 'npm start' is not working. For other react apps, npm start works well but for this particular project it does not work.
I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! c-client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the c-client@0.1.0 start script 'react-scripts start'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the c-client package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     react-scripts start
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs c-client
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls c-client
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

**NPM-debug log**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.10
3 info using node@v6.9.4
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle c-client@0.1.0~prestart: c-client@0.1.0
6 silly lifecycle c-client@0.1.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
7 info lifecycle c-client@0.1.0~start: c-client@0.1.0
8 verbose lifecycle c-client@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle c-client@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\project1\client\node_modules\.bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\PharosSystems\Core;C:\Users\sophi\Anaconda3;C:\Users\sophi\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\sophi\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\sophi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\sophi\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\sophi\AppData\Roaming\npm
10 verbose lifecycle c-client@0.1.0~start: CWD: C:\project1\client
11 silly lifecycle c-client@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
12 silly lifecycle c-client@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle c-client@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: c-client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:255:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid c-client@0.1.0
16 verbose cwd C:\project1\client
17 error Windows_NT 10.0.14393
18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
19 error node v6.9.4
20 error npm  v3.10.10
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error c-client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the c-client@0.1.0 start script 'react-scripts start'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the c-client package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     react-scripts start
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs c-client
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls c-client
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Anyone has an idea on how to solve this please?

Package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "c-client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001/",
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "0.8.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-gesture": "0.0.2-rc.12",
    "react-swipeable": "^3.9.1",
    "react-touch": "^0.4.0",
    "react-touch-events": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39970709/node-path-throws-error-when-npm-starts-on-windows-10

Comment: Thanks, I checked, and tried to perform the same change to package.json but it does not work.

Comment: can you show ur package.json file ??

Comment: Yes, just included it. Thanks

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.

Comment: I confirmed that I have the latest version installed. I imported this react application from github, and it was originally coded on a Mac and I have a Windows. Could this be a compatibility issue?

Comment: a compatibility issue should not be the problem, What do you use in Windows to run node? Cygwin or directly from CMD? Did you ran npm install to make sure you have all your modules in place ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after I restarted me computer. It was working just fine before I turned it off!... I tried for hours but in the end, in the terminal, I typed 'ls' and realised that I was in the file above the React app that I was trying to 'npm start'. I'm not presuming this might be everyone's issue, but sometimes, it's the simplest oversight. Hope this helps someone. R

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I was facing same problem but after review of directory with 'ls' realised that I am in wrong folder instead of actual.

Comment: Looks more like a comment

Answer (score 0):

Try using this if you are hosting multiple websites at a time:

1. Remove `proxy` from `package.json`.
2. Make sure you are in the right folder.
3. Type `npm start` in the terminal.

You will see a message like this:

**? Something is already running on port 3000.**

**Would you like to run the app on another port instead?** >> (Y/n)

Just type ***Y*** and hit enter.